# Angular show hide toggle on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have this ngRepeat. I want to create some sort of toggle, so that when the user clicks on the button, the input shows, however, I want all other shown inputs to hide (if they are already visible).

```
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in jewel">
         <span ng-show="!showMe">text here</span>
         <input ng-show="showMe">
         <button ng-click="showMe = true"></button>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: have you tried ng-show="!showMe" and for input ng-hide="!showMe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` has isolated scope, that is why to influence all other inputs you need to track their visibility via variable from parent scope. I've prepeared a fiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/ancvgc1b/

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($scope){
      $scope.jewel = {
        key1: 'Foo',
        key2: 'Bar'
      };
      $scope.visible = { key: 'key1' };

      $scope.setVisible = function(key) {
        $scope.visible.key = key;
      }
    });

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='ExampleController'>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in jewel">
         <span ng-show="!(visible.key == key)">Text value</span>
         <input ng-show="visible.key == key">
         <button ng-click="setVisible(key)">show input</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ng-repeat makes child scope, not isolate scope.
solution is ok but can be made less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
<ul ng-init="active={}">
     <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in jewel">
         <span ng-show="!($index==active.index)">text here</span>
         <input ng-show="$index==active.index">
         <button ng-click="active.index = $index"></button>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

If you are using controllerAs, it leads to much cleaner code as follows:
(vm is your alias to controller)

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in jewel">
         <span ng-show="!($index==vm.activeIndex)">text here</span>
         <input ng-show="$index==vm.activeIndex">
         <button ng-click="vm.activeIndex = $index"></button>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {

$scope.people = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Alpha",
    age: "24",
    clicked : false
    },
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Beta",
    age: "25",
    clicked : false
    }
];

$scope.showInput = function(person,index) {
 person.input = true;
 $scope.index = index;
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
         <span ng-show="(!person.input && (index != $index))">text here</span>
         <input ng-show="(person.input && (index == $index))">
         <button ng-click="showInput(person,$index)">Show Input</button>
    </li>
  </ul>     
</div>
```